# Suppose $M$ is a Noetherian $R$-module and $\phi: M \rightarrow M$ is an $R$-module endomorphism of $M$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

So I did an exercise in my algebra textbook which was to show that $\ker(\phi^n) \cap \operatorname{im}(\phi^n) = 0$ and show that if $\phi$ is surjective, then $\phi$ is an isomorphism.

I thought to myself and wondered if $\phi$ was injective, would $\phi$ be an isomorphism? I couldn't really think of an example or a way to prove this, so I was wondering if $\phi$ was an isomorphism if $\phi$ was injective.

Comment: The keywords for this are Hopfian and coHopfian. Noetherian modules are Hopfian, and Artinian modules are coHopfian. (Of course, that does not exhaust either type, or else we wouldn't give them new names.) related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/521309/29335

Answer (score 2):

Consider $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ multiplication by 2.

Comment: So $\phi(x) = 2x$, for $x \in \mathbb{Z}$? Isn't this an isomorphism?

Comment: @Daryl It's an isomorphism onto its image, not an automorphism of $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @Arthur Ah, I was blind to see that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*Claim:* Let $M$ be a Artinian $R$-module and let $\phi: M \to M$ be an injective $R$-module homomorphism. Then $\phi$ is an isomorphism.

Proof: First note that $\operatorname{Im}\phi \supseteq \operatorname{Im}\phi^2 \supseteq\operatorname{Im}\phi^3\supseteq \dots$ is a chain of submodules of $M.$ Since $M$ is Artinian, there exists $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $\operatorname{Im}\phi^n = \operatorname{Im}\phi^{n+1}.$ Choose a least such $n.$ Let $m \in M.$ Choose $m' \in M$ such that $\phi^n(m)=\phi^{n+1}(m') = \phi^n(\phi(m')).$ Since $\phi$ is injective, $m = \phi(m').$ Hence $\phi$ is surjective.

*Examples:* (1). Let $\phi:k[x] \to k[x], x \mapsto x^2$ be a $k$-algebra homomorphism. Then $\phi$ is injective, but not surjective. Notice that in this example the module is not Artinian.

(2). Let $\phi: k[x_1, x_2, \dots] \to k[x_1, x_2, \dots], x_i \mapsto x_{i+1}$ be a $k$-algebra homomorphism. This is injective but not surjective. Also note that the map $\psi:k[x_1, x_2, \dots] \to k[x_1, x_2, \dots], x_1 \mapsto 0, x_i \mapsto x_{i-1}, i \geq 2$ is a $k$-algebra homomorphism. This is surjective, but not injective.