# Proving $End_A(V) $ is a local ring whose Jacobson -radical is a nil-radical ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Consider the following question asked in my quiz on Algebraic Geometry.

> Let A be a ring and V be an indecomposible A-module which is artinian and well as noetherian. Then $End _AV$  is a local ring whose Jacobson -radical is a nil - radical ideal.

Attempt: Let f belongs to $ End_A V$ and Then there exists $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and $m'\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $Ker f^n = Ker f^m$ for all $n \geq m $ and $Img f^n = Img f^{m'}$, $n \leq m'$ . I can write $V =  Ker f^m \oplus Img f^{m'}$ . Now, V is indecomposible implies that either $ Kerf^m =0$ (1)or $ Img f^{m'} =0$(2).

If (1) is true then $f^m$ is injective. If (2) is true then f is nilpotent.

But still I am not sure how should I proceed to prove what is asked.

Can you please help with outlines?

Comment: Does "nil-radical ideal" mean the same thing as "nil ideal"?

Answer (score 1):

[An injective endomorphism on an Artinian module is an isomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/273181/29335).  So you have shown that all elements are nilpotent or units.

[If $x$ is nilpotent, then $1-x$ is a unit](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/119904/29335)

By [a well-known characterization of local rings](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2355275/29335) this would mean that the ring is local.  Needless to say its maximal ideal is the set of all nilpotent elements, and hence it is nil.

(Actually I found another old post which covers the two points above too: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3912461/29335)).

---

Alternatively there is an even more sledgehammery approach follows using an interesting theorem that [endomorphism rings of modules of finite length are semiprimary](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2407901/endomorphism-rings-of-finite-length-modules-are-semiprimary).  For noncommutative rings in general it may not be local because the indecomposability hypothesis was not used.  To show it is local, we have to explain why the semisimple ring $R/J(R)$ has no nontrivial idempotents, and therefore is a division ring.

If $R/J(R)$ had a nontrivial idempotent, it would [lift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotent_(ring_theory)#Category_of_R_modules) to a nontrivial idempotent of $R$. But a nontrivial idempotent of $R=End(V_A)$ by definition decomposes $V$ into two nonzero halves.  Since this has been ruled out, $R/J(R)$ is a division ring, hence $R$ is a local semiprimary ring.

Comment: "An injective endomorphism on an Artinian module is an isomorphism " How does it implies that all elements are nilpotent or units?

Comment: @Avenger You concluded that either $f$ was nilpotent or $f$ is injective. If $f$ is injective, it is a unit by the link because $V$ is artinian. So... if it's not a nilpotent, it's a unit.  What am I missing?

Comment: I  understand your comment except how does if f is injective implies that it is unit because of artinian property. can you please tell how you deduced that?

Comment: It appears a few places in the site. Here’s the first place I found https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1114694